# How to improve Ghostscript performance on scaling operation?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

For a project I'm involved in I need to resize and translate the content of a PDF
I'm using Ghostscript to achieve this goal.
The problem is that the speed lowers with the number of pages:
for a PDF with 2 pages the resize operation lasts for 0.6 seconds, while for a PDF with 100 pages the elapsed time is 10 seconds.
How can I improve Ghostscript's performance?

I used before cpdf, it was fast but it didn't preserve hyperlinks and other metadata.

```sh
   \"/usr/bin/gs\" -q -dNOPAUSE  -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dSAFER -dAutoFilterColorImages=false  -dPrinted=false -dCompatibilityLevel=1.7 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=**PDF_WIDTH** -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=**PDF_HEIGHT** -sOutputFile=**OUTPUT_PDF** -c \"80000000 setvmthreshold\" -c \"<</BeginPage{**SCALE_FACTOR** **SCALE_FACTOR** scale **TRANSLATE_X** **TRANSLATE_Y**}>> setpagedevice\" -f **INPUT_PDF**
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's really not much anyone can do to make recommendations without seeing an example of the kind of file which is causing you a problem. There could be many reasons why you are ssing this problem.

The most general explanation is:

During creation of a PDF file, the pdfwrite device maintains a considerable quantity of data in memory, **and** writes a lot of intermediate data to a small number of temporary files on disk.

For various reasons, the device needs to seek back and forth through those temporary files (not least to check for duplicate entries that can be emitted as a single object). As the size of the files increases, then seek time decreases.

In addition there are many kinds of metadata held in memory, and for various reasons these need to be checked as well. Some of those are held in complex structures, and traversing those takes more time as the number of elements (pages, forms, patterns, xobjects, colour spaces, fotns etc) increases. Even simple data objects take time to check as the number of them increases.

In short, you can't do anythiong about it, the performance decreases more or less linearly as the number of elements increases.

Since you mention a 'project', please note that Ghostscript is supplied under the AGPL v3, you might want to check that your usage is consistent with the terms of that licence before you proceeed too far.